# Laravel test POST routes with XML

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28790348/how-to-test-post-routes-in-laravel), but it's not quite what I'm after.

I have a API endpoint in a Lumen application that takes in XML. Within the controller, I'm reading data by doing this: `$request->getContent();`.

I'm trying to write a unit test that posts XML to a route and retrieve the response. I tried this `$response = $this->call('POST', '/api', $xml);`, but the third parameter has to be an array, not a string.

How would I post an XML string to an endpoint in a unit test?

Comment: Try this: `$this->call('POST', '/api', ['data' => $xml]);` then in your controller instead of `$request->getContent()` use `$request->data` to get your XML.

Comment: That won't work. I'm building an endpoint that receives data from a company. I can't specify how I'm receiving the parameters.

Comment: Please explain your xml structure, If you want dynamic parameters though xml

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The signature of the `call` is](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php#L335):

```
   /**
     * Call the given URI and return the Response.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  string  $uri
     * @param  array  $parameters
     * @param  array  $cookies
     * @param  array  $files
     * @param  array  $server
     * @param  string|null  $content
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse
     */
    public function call($method, $uri, $parameters = [], $cookies = [], $files = [], $server = [], $content = null)
```

Thus, you can pass the `xml` as the last parameter:

`$this->call('POST', '/api', [], [], [], [], $xml);`

Comment: It really was that easy. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to convert the xml string to an array as described [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578832/how-to-convert-xml-into-array-in-php) or if you just want to have the whole xml returned by calling `$request->getContent()`, then you could use the xml string as array like `$response = $this->call('POST', '/api', [$xml]);`